# How to create an isolate scope inside the view without dynamically loading templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a multi page application (yes you're heard right), where all SEO relevant content should be available initially as html and not be loaded dynamically via angular. Because of that, we would find it helpful to have a simple directive to create a new isolate scope like this for example:

```
<div some-isolate-scope-creating-directive
     ng-init="vm.someVarWithTheSameName='bla'">
   some content {{ vm.someVarWithTheSameName }}
   that should evaluate to 'bla'
</div>
<div some-isolate-scope-creating-directive
     ng-init="vm.someVarWithTheSameName='blub'">
   some content {{ vm.someVarWithTheSameName }} 
   that should evaluate to 'blub'
</div>
```

As far as I can see, the only way to achieve this, would be through transclusion, but even if I use replace, I would need to copy all the attributes and maybe even the tag name.

```
angular
  .module('myMod')
  .directive('isolateScope', isolateScope);

/* @ngInject */
function isolateScope() {
  return {
    bindToController: true,
    controller: 'someCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    // stupid if we have section for example
    // or some classes or other attributes
    template:'<div ng-transclude></div>',
    restrict: 'A', 
    // use replace as we don't want any other html
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    // create isolate scope
    scope: {
    }
  };
}
```

I was hoping that there maybe is a better way to do this.

Comment: Use components: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component. Components have isolated scopes.
And by the way: I think you create a Single Page Application(SPA) instead of a Multi Page Application :).

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek no it's a multi-page application with server side rendered pages. Components don't solve anything here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution would be to create an empty controller and simply use `ng-controller` to create a new scope, e.g.:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.1/angular.js"></script>
<script>
   angular
    .module('myMod',[]);
  
   angular
    .module('myMod')
    .controller('EmptyCtrl', function(){
    });
</script>
<body ng-app="myMod">
<div data-ng-controller="EmptyCtrl as vm"
     ng-init="vm.someVarWithTheSameName='bla'">
    some content "{{ vm.someVarWithTheSameName }}"
    that should evaluate to 'bla' and does, because
    it has it's own isolated scope
</div>
<div data-ng-controller="EmptyCtrl as vm"
     ng-init="vm.someVarWithTheSameName='hihihi'; vm.someOtherVar='HAHAHA'">
    some content "{{ vm.someVarWithTheSameName }}"
    that should evaluate to 'hihihi' and does, because
    it has it's own isolated scope
</div>
<div>some non existing content "{{vm.someOtherVar}}" as
     vm.someOtherVar is defined in isolate scope</div>
<div ng-init="vm.someVarWithTheSameName='blublub'">
    some content "{{ vm.someVarWithTheSameName }}"
    that should evaluate to 'blublub', but doesn't
    because it is on the global scope
</div>
<div ng-init="vm.someVarWithTheSameName='bliip'">
    some content "{{ vm.someVarWithTheSameName }}"
    that should evaluate to 'bliip', and does
    because it's defined last
</div>
</body>
```